# lightbox video popup for youtube channel video

Tags: javascript

When I click on the image video popups but does not play i.e. shows only loading symbol.

My js code is

```
function showVideoList(channelid, rows, maxnumbervideos, apikey) {
        try {               
            var videoinfo = JSON.parse(getJSONData("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=" + channelid + "&maxResults=" + maxnumbervideos + "&key=" + apikey));

            var videos = videoinfo.items;
            var videocount = videoinfo.pageInfo.totalResults;
            // video listing                

             for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
             debugger;
                //document.body.innerHTML+= "<div class='row'>" ;
                // var div = document.getElementById("row");
                //var append = "<div class='row'>"
                 $("#row").append("<div class='row'></div>");

                    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        var videoid = videos[i].id.videoId;
                        var videotitle = videos[i].snippet.title;
                        var videodescription = videos[i].snippet.description;
                        var videodate = videos[i].snippet.publishedAt; // date time published
                        var videothumbnail = videos[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url; // default, medium or high
                         $('div.row').last().append("<div class='col s12 m4 l4'>"
                            + "<div class='blog-post'>" + " <div class='card'> " + " <div class='card-image'> "
                            + "<a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoid + " target='_blank' class='voverlay'>"
                            + "<img src='" + videothumbnail + "' style='border:none;float:left;margin-right:10px;' alt='" + videotitle + "' title='" 
                            + videotitle + "' /></a>"
                            +"</div>" 
                            + " <div class='card-content blog-post-content'> "
                            + "<h2><a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoid + "' target='_blank'>" + videotitle + "</a></h2>" 
                            + " <div class='meta-media'> "
                            + "<div class='single-meta'>" + " Post By <a href='#'>Admin</a>" + " </div> "
                            + " <div class='single-meta'> " + "  Category : <a href='#'>Web/Design</a> " + " </div> "
                            + " </div> "
                            + " <div class='card-action'> "
                            + "  <a class='post-comment' href='#'><i class='material-icons'>comment</i><span>15</span></a> "
                            + "  <a class='readmore-btn' href='blog-single.html'>Read More</a> "
                            + " </div> "                                
                            +"</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>"
                            );                      
                    }
                document.body.innerHTML+="</div>";
                // append += "</div>";
            //  div.innerHTML = append;
                }   
        } catch (ex) {
            alert(ex.message);              
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's your getjsondata method?

Comment: did you mean the values for the parameters channelid, rows, maxnumbervideos, apikey      <script type="text/javascript">
        showVideoList("........", "row", 3, "...............");
    </script>